# Update rows based off of data from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which keeps schedule records - our scheduler uses a specific set of colors to show the current status of appointments which is saved in a table in MySQL - more data regarding these appointments is saved in a separate table in mysql - (this is the only way this database will work because some appointments will not be scheduled at all times in which case they will exist in the "calls" table and not in the "appointments" table

Table design:

```
appointments
Uniqueid | Label | CustomField1
    1    |   1   |      22
    2    |   1   |      31
    3    |   1   |      76

calls
RID | Rentry | Rdisp | Rconf | Renrt | Ronsc | Rtrans | Rdest | Rclr
 22 |  <dt>  |  <dt> |  NULL | NULL  |  NULL  |  NULL |  NULL | NULL
 31 |  <dt>  |  <dt> |  <dt> | NULL  |  NULL  |  NULL |  NULL | NULL
 50 |  <dt>  |  NULL |  NULL | NULL  |  NULL  |  NULL |  NULL | NULL
 76 |  <dt>  |  <dt> |  <dt> | <dt>  |  <dt>  |  NULL |  NULL | NULL
```

CustomField1 represents the RID of the same row in "calls". I need to run an update statement that updates "Label" based off if there is a value in Rdisp | Rconf | Renrt | Ronsc | Rtrans | Rdest | Rclr.

Essentially running off the following pattern:

```
not null | Label value
 Rdisp   |    0
 Rconf   |    1
 Renrt   |    2
 Ronsc   |    3 
 Rtrans  |    4
 Rdest   |    5
 Rclr    |    6
```

in a select statement I would left join but I am not sure if that is possible in an update statement

so essentially

```
UPDATE `appointments` SET `Label` = 0 WHERE `Rdisp` IS NOT NULL;
UPDATE `appointments` SET `Label` = 1 WHERE `Rconf` IS NOT NULL;
UPDATE `appointments` SET `Label` = 2 WHERE `Renrt` IS NOT NULL;
UPDATE `appointments` SET `Label` = 3 WHERE `Ronsc` IS NOT NULL;
UPDATE `appointments` SET `Label` = 4 WHERE `Rtrans` IS NOT NULL;
UPDATE `appointments` SET `Label` = 5 WHERE `Rdest` IS NOT NULL;
UPDATE `appointments` SET `Label` = 6 WHERE `Rclr` IS NOT NULL;
```

but we would have to join/link appointments.customField1 to calls.RID

New join statement:

```
UPDATE appointments a JOIN calls c 
ON a.CustomField1 = c.RID
SET a.Label = 0
WHERE `Rdisp` IS NOT NULL
```

and preferably make this transaction one process.

How would I link these tables in this situation and is it possible to make this one statement

Comment: You can use `JOIN` in an update. You obviously have more than one `NULL` value in the `R` columns. Are you wanting the highest label value then? In your example data, you want all the labels to be 6 since `Rclr` is `NULL` for all of them?

Comment: I have added the "join" update statement to my question - yes highest label value would be the one to display but no none of them would be 6 because it runs when it is not null  (76 would be 3, 31 would be 1 and 22 would be 0)

Comment: I recognize I could run 7 separate statements at one time (separated by ;) however I am wondering at this point if there is a more direct way to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to using `JOIN` in an `UPDATE` statement, you can also use `CASE`:

```
UPDATE appointments a
JOIN calls c 
ON c.RID = a.CustomField1
SET a.Label = CASE
WHEN c.Rclr IS NOT NULL THEN 6
WHEN c.Rdest IS NOT NULL THEN 5
WHEN c.Rtrans IS NOT NULL THEN 4
WHEN c.Ronsc IS NOT NULL THEN 3
WHEN c.Renrt IS NOT NULL THEN 2
WHEN c.Rconf IS NOT NULL THEN 1
WHEN c.Rdisp IS NOT NULL THEN 0
END
```

You also may want an `ELSE` statement there for a default value.